# Hbase Multiple Master issue

Tags: hbase

I am evaluating HBase Multiple master utility as I require that functionality. I used a simple 4 machine hbase cluster with M1 as master. Now I started the Hmaster in M4 as well. I could see logs in M4 Master log as, This HMaster is waiting as already M1 is acting as HMaster.

After this I stopped the Master in the M1 and after few seconds, the M4 master took over. But I am not seeing any region server communicating to this new master. The region server logs show,

```
2011-10-31 23:21:18,834 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer: Unable to connect to master. Retrying. Error was: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) 
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:574) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:404) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:311) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:865) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:732) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC$Invoker.invoke(HBaseRPC.java:257) 
        at $Proxy3.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:419) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:393) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:444) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:349) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getMaster(HRegionServer.java:1443) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.tryRegionServerReport(HRegionServer.java:737) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:586) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Also in the M4 Master log I am seeing,

```
2011-10-31 23:20:47,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 60010 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 60010 
2011-10-31 23:20:47,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 60010 
2011-10-31 23:20:47,671 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26 
2011-10-31 23:20:48,691 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010 
2011-10-31 23:20:48,691 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Started service threads 
2011-10-31 23:20:50,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Waiting on regionserver(s) to checkin 
2011-10-31 23:20:51,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Waiting on regionserver(s) to checkin 
2011-10-31 23:20:53,197 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Waiting on regionserver(s) to checkin
```

Seems the region servers are only communicating to the M1 Hmaster and not to the new one!!

I am using Hbase - 0.90.0 version

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Today saw the zookeeper to make sure whether the new master is getting registered in it or not. Just used the zk_dump and the new master is present as current master node in zookeeper.

But still this is not considered by region servers. I expected the region servers would update the master info in them by communicating with the zoo keeper. But doesn't seem to happen here. Any suggestions Plz !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this works fine with Hbase 0.90.3. Need to verify though!!

http://old.nabble.com/Hbase-Multiple-Master-issue-td32757197.html#a32758542